# NestJS + Mongoose schema with a custom typescript Type

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-schema

I'm Trying to create a Mongo Schema, using `nestjs/mongoose` decorators, from the following class:

```js
@Schema()
export class Constraint {
  @Prop()
  reason: string;

  @Prop()
  status: Status;

  @Prop()
  time: number;
}
```

The problem is `Status` is defined as followed:

```js
export type Status = boolean | 'pending';
```

And I cannot figure out what to pass to the `status`'s `prop` decorator, since I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Cannot determine a type for the "Constraint.status" field (union/intersection/ambiguous type was used). Make sure your property is decorated with a "@Prop({ type: TYPE_HERE })" decorator
```

and `{ type: Status }` doesn't work, since `Status` is a `type` and not a `Class`.

Comment: Hello,
I am facing the same problem, did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `status` can be a boolean or a string it's a mixed type. So you can look into setting your type to [Mixed](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and thanks to @sven-stam, as he mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75209720/12002195), I implemented Mixed type like this:

```js
import { Prop, Schema } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import mongoose, {
  HydratedDocument,
  Schema as MongooseSchema,
} from 'mongoose';

export type UserDocument = HydratedDocument<User>;

@Schema()
class User {
  @Prop()
  username: string

  @Prop({default: false, type: MongooseSchema.Types.Mixed })
  paid: boolean | 'waiting'
}
```